# Block Sweet32 attacks on a Fortigate?

Tags: fortigate

I have a Fortigate product running FortiOS 5.4.x and I can't mitigate the [Sweet32 vulnerability](https://sweet32.info/).

I've already enabled the high security algorithms and disabled the SSL3 / TLS1.0 for Beast & Crime as shown below.

```
config system global 
  set strong-crypto enable 
  end

config vpn ssl setting 
   set sslv3 disable 
   set tls1-0 disable
```

How can I address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [FortiOS 5.4.1 CLI Reference](http://docs.fortinet.com/d/fortigate-fortios-5.4-cli-reference) it is possible to block specific cipher suites such as 3DES from being used. There is little documentation on the use of this option but I have verified it does indeed function as needed. 
Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a matching command in 5.2 or earlier.

```
config vpn ssl setting 
   banned-cipher 3DES
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Fortinet has a new patch for their firmware to resolve this issue.

Build 1100

This was the only way to resolve my issue with the Sweet32

Scanned and confirmed.

---

I'm having the same issue. Using his (Tim Brigham) note, I was able to find the CLI code.

config vpn.ssl settings

edit

set reqclientcert {enable | disable}

set sslv3 {enable | disable}

set tlsv1-0 {enable | disable}

set tlsv1-1 {enable | disable}

set tlsv1-2 {enable | disable}

set banned-cipher {RSA | DH | DHE | ECDH | ECDHE | DSS | ECDSA | AES | AESGCM |

CA

MELLIA | 3DES | SHA1 | SHA256 | SHA384}

Taken from

http://docs.fortinet.com/uploaded/files/2798/fortigate-cli-ref-54.pdf

Page 756

**Commands:**

## #config vpn ssl settings

*Note if you use the config vpn.ssl settings it will come as an error.

## #set banned-cipher 3DES

*without the set, it comes as an unknown on my CLI

I'm running my PCI scanner to verify completion. Will update once confirmed.

** Did not resolve PCI failure **

---

** Update ** 11/1/2016 (Ignore as this did not resolve the issue Either*)

I had to call into the support line and this is what I found. 1 (866) 868-3678 (expect a long hold time, quick resolve once connected)

The SSL Cert for me has been the default Fortinet_Factory which is outdated. On version 5.4.x there is another setting called Fortinet_SSL which is updated and correct. On 5.2.x they will need to set you with the updated system. No idea how to do this, but that's what the tech said.

### config vpn ssl settings

### sh ful (shows your current settings)

### set servercert (shows which certs are available)

### set servercert Fortinet_FacotrySSL

### end

### endset servercert Fortinet_SSLh fulconfig vpn ssl settingsshow | grep -f factoryFortinet_Factory

config user setting
    set auth-type http https
    set auth-cert "Fortinet_Factory" <---
    set auth-secure-http enable
end

## config user setting

(setting) #

(setting) # set auth-typecert Fortinet_CA_SSLProxyUntrustedFactorySSL

(setting) # end

I would recommend calling in and having them set this, as there isn't really a good walk through that I could find. I just basically logged the SSH and copy pasted the commands that they put in.

This is what shows as my PCI Failing before the update >

TLSv1_1 : ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA

TLSv1_1 : EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA

TLSv1_1 : DES-CBC3-SHA

TLSv1_2 : ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA

TLSv1_2 : EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA

TLSv1_2 : DES-CBC3-SHA

I did the strong-crypto enable and the set banned-cipher 3DES which did not resolve these.

SSL change did not resolve the issue ***

---

Called in again 11/2/2016. Was told that the system needed to be patched.

Updated to 5.4.2 build 1100.